# Who is the Arba'ah Turei Even?

Tags: rabbis, historical-figures, acharonim

In the back of the Frankel printing of the Rambam, they have a section of collected commentaries. One of them is a work titled "Arba'ah Turei Even." The Frankel bio page identifies the author as אלעזר רוקח, av beis din of Brod and Amsterdam, buried in Tzfas. My HebrewBooks search has the work published in 1789.

I am curious who he was, in terms of who his teachers were, what positions he held, and if he had any well-known students. Accounts of how he was regarded by others would also be helpful.

In general, I am trying to get a picture of his significance and authority. These are the factors that I think would be helpful, although any other info to this end would be appreciated.

Comment: If you like an answer consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 3):

> [R. Elazar Rokach (1665 - 1741)] served in a number of Polish communities, but is most famous for his rabbinate in Brody from 1714 to 1735, when he was called to serve as rabbi of Amsterdam. Upon arrival to this city, the Jewish community issued a coin in his honor. After a number of years, he decided to emigrate to the Holy Land. During Sukkot 1740 he reached Safad and [a] year [later] passed away.
>
> The Arba'ah Turei Even was published in 1789 in Lemberg by his grandson, R. Naphtali Hertz in Brody. In the 1900 Vilna edition of the Mishneh Torah, the explanations [to the] Rambam [were] copied and entitled Turei Even and since then in standard editions of the Rambam. Most of the volume deals for the most part with the first book, Sefer HaMada and he deals with almost each law, while only a few comments [are] on the rest of the Rambam.

(From the Bar-Ilan bio.)